# Details dont remain in the form when it is refreshed

Tags: php, forms

I have made a contact form with server side validation and it work fine. When information is entered with an unnoticed error the form is returned back highlighting it. When i returns the fields that are previously been filled in are empty regardless if there is an error with that field. I'm wanting to have the form returned back to the user with the information that they have put in to a filed remain there until the form passes the validation.

This is my code to validate the PHP

```
<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$firstnameErr = $secondnameErr = $emailaddressErr = $commentErr = $captchaErr = "";
$firstname = $email = $secondname = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
  $firstnameErr = "First name is required";
} else {
  $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
  // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname)) {
    $firstnameErr = "Invalid first name"; 
  }
}

 if (empty($_POST["secondname"])) {
  $secondnameErr = "Second name is required";
 } else {
 $secondname = test_input($_POST["secondname"]);
 // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$secondname)) {
   $secondnameErr = "Invalid second name"; 
 }
 }

if (empty($_POST["emailaddress"])) {
  $emailaddressErr = "Email address is required";
 } else {
  $emailaddress = test_input($_POST["emailaddress"]);
  // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
  if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$emailaddress)) {
    $emailaddressErr = "Invalid email format"; 
  }
 }

 if (empty($_POST["comment"])) {
  $commentErr = "Enter a message";
 } else {
 $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$comment)) {
   $commentErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
 }

  if (empty($_POST["captcha"])) {
 $captchaErr = "Enter the answer to the sum";
 } else {
 $captcha = test_input($_POST["captcha"]);
 // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$captcha)) {
   $captchaErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
 }
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>
```

And this is my form

```
<form name="Contact" form id="Contact" onsubmit=" return validate()" METHOD="POST"     action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">


<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">First Name:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="firstname" class="detail" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required   />
<span class="error"><?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>    </div> 
<!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row--><br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Second Name:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="text" id="secondname" class="detail" name="secondname" placeholder="Second Name" required />
<span class="error"><?php echo $secondnameErr;?></span>    </div> 
<!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row-->


<br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Email Address:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<input type="email" id="emailaddress" class="detail" name="emailaddress" placeholder="Email Address"  />
<span class="error"><?php echo $emailaddressErr;?></span>     
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row-->

    <br />
<div class="Row">
<div class="Lable">Your Message:</div> <!--End of Lable-->
<div class="input">
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess" placeholder="Your Message" minlength="10" required ></textarea>
<span class="error"><?php echo $commentErr;?></span>     
</div> <!--End input-->
</div> <!--End row--> 

<br />
<input id="number1" name="number1" readonly="readonly" class="Add" value="<?php echo rand(1,4) ?>" /> + 
<input id="number2" name="number2" readonly="readonly" class="Add" value="<?php echo rand(5,9) ?>" /> =
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" class="captcha" maxlength="2" />
<div class="Lable">Please give the correct answer to the sum</div>
<br />
<span class="captchaerror"><?php echo $captchaErr;?></span>     
<br />

<br />
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" id="send" Name="send" value="Send"  />
</div><!--End of submit-->

<div class="Clear">
<input type="reset" id="clear" Name="Clear" value="Clear" />
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: make sure you have session_start in php script where you have form and where you make validation. also you need to have value of every field saved in session ..

Comment: If you don't show the code, it's impossible to give you advice. We have no idea how your site works.

Comment: Make sure you are saving the values in some fashion (like session) and then putting them back into the form on refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form action is same page, that is the php codes for validation and all are on the same page, you can echo the post/get values to corresponding fields except passwords. Otherwise store post/get values on  session variables or as cookie and then echo these values as field values for corresponding fields except passwords.

Answer (score -1):

here is your solution

**form_page.php**

```
<form action="form_submit.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" value="<?php echo @$_POST['text1'];?>" />
  <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" value="<?php echo @$_POST['text2'];?>" />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**form_submit.php**

```
<?php
  $text1 = $_POST['text1'];
  $text2 = $_POST['text2'];

  $error = false;
  if($text1=="")
  {
     $error = true;
     echo "Text 1 is blank";
  } 
  else if($text1=="")
  {
     $error = true;
     echo "Text 2 is blank";
  }
  else
  {
     // do your work
  }

  if($error)
  {
     include("form_page.php");
  }
  else
  {
     header(location:"form_page.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: @itachi have you seen the code properly. when the page is load first time $_POST['text1'] is not set `@` skips the error for it. when page is submit and got any error `($error=true)` include the form_page.php in `form_submit.php` now $_POST['text1'] is available and shown in textbox as typed before submit.

Comment: -1 was for `@` is _NOT_ a solution to anything. above represents a __very__ bad code habit.

Comment: the only solution  except `@` is that `value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['text1'])) ? $_POST['text1'] : ""; ?>";`